Error 'CLR20r3' calling external aplication
I have a portal in Python 3.11 and Django 5.0.8 this portal in some point calls a external app developed in vb.net, this is the way i call the vb.net app subprocess.call('C:\\some\\Direction\\ExternalApp.exe', 'parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3', 'parameter4', ...), i have tried the portal with IIS 10 on windows 11 and the python server and works fine, but when use in the IIS 10 on windows server 2022 standard gives me error, and using the python server on WS 2022 works fine, this is the error that shows me the event viewer:
Aplicación: ExternaApp.exe
Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
   en System.Data.DataView.GetRow(Int32)
   en System.Data.DataView.get_Item(Int32)
   en ExternalApp.cls.function(Int32, Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
   en ExternalApp.DM1.Main()

Nombre de la aplicación con errores: ExternalApp.exe, versión: 1.0.0.0, marca de tiempo: 0x66f5c058
Nombre del módulo con errores: KERNELBASE.dll, versión: 10.0.20348.2227, marca de tiempo: 0xe95c736c
Código de excepción: 0xe0434352
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x000000000003f19c
Identificador del proceso con errores: 0x3804
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01db113917154b04
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\some\direction\ExternalApp.exe
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Identificador del informe: c2dd5273-2d2d-4f89-9f3c-136d4f99f49a
Nombre completo del paquete con errores: 
Identificador de aplicación relativa del paquete con errores: 

Depósito con errores 2097650123060317690, tipo 5
Nombre de evento: CLR20r3
Respuesta: No disponible
Identificador de archivo .cab: 0

Firma del problema:
P1: ExternalApp.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 66f5c058
P4: System.Data
P5: 4.8.4690.0
P6: 6567d997
P7: e82
P8: b
P9: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
P10: 

I even tried execute te erternal app with comands on cmd and the app works fine, so works executing with comands and using the portal with python web server but not in IIS, i think that could be some permission problem but i can solve this

I can clearly see the exception name in the error message: IndexOutOfRangeException. As for how to locate the problem based on this information, you can use the IL Disassembler tool in Visual Studio to assist you. Just refer to this similar case: Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10
And the data corresponding to P1 is your external application instead of w3wp.exe, so I think this problem may not be related to IIS, but more likely a method in your code is incompatible with the .NET framework version. You can try to install different version to check if this work: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48
